# Why does the same material looks brighter/darker on another object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, shaders

I have applied all transforms, recalculated normals, unwrapped every piece. While trying to maintain pixel density (first ever modkit so correct me if I'm wrong but it is the faces' size on the UV map).

[image]

Still, the two corner piece on the left are brighter. Driving me crazy...! 
Edit: tried both eevee, cycles
Any idea as well as comments, critiques are welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello and welcome, if i may ask, can it be that the first two lighter parts are in smooth shading and the rest is in flat shading? The edges of the first two kinda look a bit rounded while the other ones seem rather sharp. Not sure if that can cause your problem, but if you do not mind, sharing your file with all not related parts removed could help finding your problem. You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), where you will need the **address of your question** to be able to upload and generate a download link.

Comment: Thanks for mini guide about blend share :)  Appreciate the shading idea, unfortunately did not work :(

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=vBjNAAK1" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vBjNAAK1/)

Comment: I'm positive it's got something to do with the UV-map. I've simplified your meshes into two identical cubes and, though the difference in brightness remained the same, it could be altered by re-unwrapping the objects. When both object's UV-maps were equal, however, the difference in shade also disappeared. What's been puzzling me is that unwrapping the cubes via smart or cube projections yields different brightness levels on the applied texture.

Comment: Thank you #impresso! You were right about uv, but I still could not get it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seemed to come from the orientation of the UV unwrapped faces.

I didn't have the same textures, but replaced the missing 2 textures with concrete and stone wall textures to check. First i could not find the problem, as shading, normals and even custom normals did not help. Then i unwrapped the 2 parts from scratch and gave them more seams to have a clean unwrap, not the "Smart UV Project".

I then made sure the selected areas were given each the materials to have a similar result as was shown in the question:
[image]

Using a sun light to check the shadowing of the wall sections, the smaller one always seemed to be reacting exactly the opposite way then the big one.
 When i pointed the sun on the walls the smaller one became dark, and when i directed the light away it became bright.
[image]
As of that moment, considering that i tried all the other options mentioned, i had only one other idea: **UV map**.

I selected the UV map of the small corner wall and rotated it by 90° by selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>R</kbd> followed by typing in 90 and confirmed it with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the process shown below:
[image]

The result was this:
[image]

Also regarding the pixel density, i believe the easiest way would be to select all involved objects **after** they are unwrapped, go in UV Editing and select all elements <kbd>A</kbd>, to then use the "Average Islands Scale" function in the UV menu:
[image]

Happy Blending

Comment: Wow! That's awesome #Xylvier!  I appreciate your detailed answer, solution and the tip as well! I will get back to it ASAP and finally carry on with a clear mind :)